# Local database with later opt-in

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wrote an app that contains data that is sensitive to certain users which so not want it to end up online. I want to allow to use the app with firebase offline only with the option to sync at a later time. Is this possible with current ios and android firebase implementations as a replacement for sqlite database?

Comment: ```not want it to end up online``` - compliance, export restrictions, espionage act? Just so you know, you can specify **security rules** so that only logged in user can access their data.

Comment: I know about the security rules but the data can be accessed by the firebase admins as well as Google. And there is no security, that is absolutely safe so they just don't feel comfortable to have it in the cloud. It is a matter of personal preference and I would like to know if it is possible.

Comment: Google datacenter - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDAYZU4A3w0 - if I was worried about rogue admins... ```don't feel comfortable to have it in the cloud``` - don't use cloud service then. ```firebase offline only``` - it feels greatly counterintuitive... But maybe there is a way, maybe there is a valid use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Database is primarily an online database that can handle intermittent and medium-term lack of connectivity.

While the user is not connected, Firebase will keep a queue of pending write operations. It will aggregate those operations locally when it loads the data from disk into memory. This means that the larger the number of write operations while the user is offline, the longer loading will take and the more memory the database will use.

This is not a problem in the intended use-case: online apps that need to handle short/medium term lack of connectivity. But it is not a suitable database for long-term offline databases.

Comment: Is this actually still the case? The latest docs talk about full offline support. It also states that write operations are now applied to a local instance and are synced later on.

Comment: Yes, this is still the case.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks anyway.